# Nested Nuxt page says computed property not defined when navigating to another page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have nested pages that look like this:

```
/pages/services/index.vue
/pages/services/service-1.vue
...
```

The `index.vue` and `service-1.vue` pages use two different layouts. The layout for `service-1.vue` has a `computed()` function like the below.

```
computed: {
 currentService() {
   return this.$store.getters.getServiceByUrl(this.$route.path)
 }
```

When on `service-1.vue`, if I click a `<nuxt-link to='/services'>` (or any other page) I get an error saying "_vm.currentService is undefined". At this point, if I try to navigate to *another* page (or simply refresh the current page) the error goes away and the page renders as expected.

I don't understand why this is happening though. Only `/services/service-1.vue` is using a layout with that computed property, so why is it even being looked for on any other route?